# Javascript code not running on some webpages

Tags: javascript, php, html

Am new to javascript. Am trying to display errors in my project webpages in the form of `span`. So i used javascript code to input a certain text into the span through its id as the following:

```
//Checking if passwords match
if ($password1 != $password2) {
  //$error1 = "Passwords don't match";
  $error1 = "var error = document.getElementById('error1')
             error.textContent = 'Passwords don't match'
             error.style.color = 'red'";
  //echo $error1;
}else {
  $error1 = null;
}
```

The id is linked to the following HTML span:

```
<div id="password2">
   <label>Confirm password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="pw2" required>
   <span id="error1"></span>
</div>
```

And then i run the javascript code inside HTML in the `<script>` tag as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  <?php echo $error1,$error2; ?>
</script>
```

That method worked fine in other two webpages same way but in this one it doesn't. Also the code works fine as i tested the code using PHP `echo` and it output same string.

Comment: At the top, use something like `$dontMatch = $password1 != $password2;`, then inside your form, use `<?php if ($dontMatch) echo "<span class='error'>Passwords don't match</span>"; ?>`. Style the `error` class accordingly. What you are doing is convoluted and error prone, and dependent on JS being active.

Comment: So you suggest i don't use javascript at all? @ChrisG

Comment: Also how would i position the span tag with rest of HTML when i echo it?

Comment: Like this: https://ideone.com/U0OJnU (use JS if useful or necessary, but don't put JS code literals in PHP variables, and echo them into scripts, I've truly never seen anybody do this before, it's creative, I'll give you that ;)

Comment: Please share more details - how does the **generated** markup look like in case it works, and how in case it doesnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the answer was not use javascript as i did at all, e.g.:

```
<?php
 
$password1 = "hello";
$password2 = "yello";
 
$dontMatch = $password1 != $password2;
 
?>
<div id="password2">
   <label>Confirm password:</label>
   <input type="password" name="pw2" required>
   <?php if ($dontMatch) echo "<span class='error'>Passwords don't match</span>" . PHP_EOL; ?>
</div>
```